# Get back to an activity having fragments and resume it

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, onresume

I hope you all are doing well.
I am facing difficulty in making an Android App in **java**.
I have an activity A, which has 4 fragments in it(working with bottom nav bar). I go to my 3rd fragment and there I press a button to open another Activity B.
What I want is that when I press ***go back*** text in Activity B, I move to Activity A with the same fragment 3 loaded.

*NOTE: Any helping material would be useful to me. So kindly share any source link or any knowledge you guys have about it*

**Thanks**

Comment: I think you need save the fragment that is loaded before and then when reloading check which fragment has to be loaded  and load that

Answer (score 1):

I just found the simplest solution. Add a click listener on back icon and simply just add finish() in it. like this:

```
goback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Explanation:
fragment keeps its state automatically in the stack and when we choose to do finish() on button click, the current running activity's life span ends and then on the stack, the fragment's state is available and it resumes automatically.